# camel - how to propagate a correlationId through producerTemplates

Tags: java, apache-camel

This post relates to this [get exchange from within pojo without changing it's interface](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-Exchange-from-a-within-a-POJO-without-changing-the-interface-td4633681.html)

and the solution to this problem was to use MDC.

here is the code to do so: (taken from camel test code)

given this interface for instance

```
    public interface IEcho {
        String echo(String param);
    }
```

and configuration like so :

```
    import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
    import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
    import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
    import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.slf4j.MDC;

    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

    public class RetrieveCorrelationIdTest {

        @Test
        public void testCamel() throws Exception {
            DefaultCamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
            try {
                ctx.setUseMDCLogging(true);
                ctx.addRoutes(createRouteBuilder());
                ctx.start();
                Object body = ctx.createProducerTemplate().requestBody("direct:a", "text in body");
                assertEquals("TEXT IN BODY", body);
            } finally {
                ctx.stop();
            }
        }

        protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
            return new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    IEcho proxy = (IEcho) ReflectHelper.simpleProxy(IEcho.class, new Proxybean(getContext()));

                    from("direct:a").routeId("route-a")
                            .setHeader("CUSTOM-CORRELATION-ID", constant("correlationIdsetInHeader"))
                            .process(exchange -> MDC.put("CUSTOM-HEADER-MDC", "correlationIdsetWithMDC"))
                            .bean(proxy, "echo(${body})");

                    from("direct:b").routeId("route-b")
                            .process(exchange -> {
                                String customHeader = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CUSTOM-CORRELATION-ID");
                                String mdcHeader = MDC.get("CUSTOM-HEADER-MDC");
                                assertEquals(customHeader, mdcHeader);
                                exchange.getIn().setBody(((String)exchange.getIn().getBody()).toUpperCase());
                            })
                            .to("mock:result");
                }
            };
        }

        class Proxybean implements InvocationHandler {
            CamelContext ctx;
            Proxybean(CamelContext ctx) {
                this.ctx = ctx;
            }
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                if (method.getName().equals("echo")) {
                    // how to get the CUSTOM-CORRELATION-ID here ????µ
                    // only possible with MDC ?
                    String mdcHeader = MDC.get("CUSTOME-HEADER-MDC");
                    String result =
                            (String) ctx.createProducerTemplate()
                                    .requestBodyAndHeader("direct:b", args[0], "CUSTOME-HEADER", mdcHeader);
                    return result;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

see comments in code:

```
// how to get the CUSTOM-CORRELATION-ID here ????µ
// only possible with MDC ?
```

I can access some data even without the exchange using MDC

**so my questions:**

if I want to get a correlationId spanning from an endpoint calling beans method that calls other method exposed through a proxy that uses a producerTemplate to make the call etc etc...

- Is that possible without MDC, does camel offers another way to retrieve this information?

Comment: See the exchange properties as ids are stored there

Comment: yes,I can retrieve info of the correlation id.. in the exchange, but how can I get them if I don't have the exchange at hand, but I know that I am on the same thread...if I call MDC.get, I can also have this info, but is there another mechanism in camel to get them without the need for log4j or logback. if not well, perhaps I can implement the same principles that does not require log4j, it seems it's only one class to implement. (in logback it seems they use ThreadLocal)

Comment: Use the API from producer template that returns an Exchange to get them

Comment: Thx claus, I added some more info to better illustrate my question, in the proxy, I can access data through MDC (linked to ThreadLocal) but this requires MDC (as far as I know) so a logging framework implementing this. Is there another way to do it ? or is it the only way right now. regards